# getDisplayString() in omnet++ doesn't change the displayed string of the message

Tags: c++, omnet++

according to omnet++ docs [here](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cMessage.html#aca22dc8e5945f69f69fc03ae64464653), in order to change the display string of a message during the simulation, I have to override the function called `getDisplayString()` as they said:

> ◆ getDisplayString()
>
> virtual const char* getDisplayString  (       )   const
>
> Override to define a display string for the message. Display string affects message appearance in Qtenv. This default implementation returns "".

so I did as they said and here is the code of my custom message:

```
class MyMsg_Base : public ::omnetpp::cPacket
{
  protected:
    uint8_t M_Header = 0;
    omnetpp::opp_string M_Payload;
    uint8_t M_Trailer = 0;
    int M_Type = 0;

  private:
    void copy(const MyMsg_Base& other);

  protected:
    bool operator==(const MyMsg_Base&) = delete;

    // make assignment operator protected to force the user override it
    MyMsg_Base& operator=(const MyMsg_Base& other);

  public:
    // make constructors protected to avoid instantiation
    MyMsg_Base(const char *name=nullptr, short kind=0);
    MyMsg_Base(const MyMsg_Base& other);

    virtual ~MyMsg_Base();
    virtual MyMsg_Base *dup() const override {return new MyMsg_Base(*this);}
    virtual void parsimPack(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b) const override;
    virtual void parsimUnpack(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b) override;

    virtual uint8_t getM_Header() const;
    virtual void setM_Header(uint8_t M_Header);

    virtual const char * getM_Payload() const;
    virtual void setM_Payload(const char * M_Payload);

    virtual uint8_t getM_Trailer() const;
    virtual void setM_Trailer(uint8_t M_Trailer);

    virtual int getM_Type() const;
    virtual void setM_Type(int M_Type);

    virtual const char *getDisplayString() const override
    {
        EV << "ECHO" << std::endl;
        return "whyyyyyyyyyyyy";

    }
};
```

but when I simulate this happens:
[image]

as you can see `EV << "ECHO" << std::endl;` is executed so this means that `getDisplayString()` is called successfully as I didn't call `EV << "ECHO" << std::endl;` anywhere else in the project.

but the display string of the message is "(MyMsg_Base)" and it didn't change as the docs said, so what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is NOT the display string you are seeing on the picture. That is the NAME of the message. DisaplyString is meant to change the **graphical** appearance of the message on Qtenv. (i.e. color, shape etc)

Comment: Tip: if you want to change the message displayString, you don't have to create a customized message class with Base class etc. Just add the 'displayString' property to your .msg file in the message definition and the generated calss will have a set/getDisplayString() method that you can use to set anything there.